# How much memory does a reference use on the stack

Tags: c++, linux

How much memory of an object goes onto the stack when using pass by reference?
I thought using pass by reference would not make a copy of the object and there would not be the size of the object on the stack.
In the code below it seems as though the **entire size of the object** is being pushed onto the stack whether it is a reference or value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

struct structWithSize_s{
  char data[1024*2];
};

void usePassPointer(structWithSize_s *t,uint64_t addr){
    int i;
    std::cout << "usePassPointer: stack: " << std::hex << &i 
              << std::dec << " size on stack: " << addr-uint64_t(&i) << std::endl;
    i = int(t->data[0]);
}
void usePassByValue(structWithSize_s t,uint64_t addr){
    int i;
    std::cout << "usePassByValue: stack: " << std::hex << &i 
              << std::dec << " size on stack: " << addr-uint64_t(&i) << std::endl;
    i = int(t.data[0]);
    usePassPointer(&t,uint64_t(&i));
}
void usePassByRef(structWithSize_s &t,uint64_t addr){
    int i;
    std::cout << "usePassByRef: stack: " << std::hex << &i 
              << std::dec << " size on stack: " << addr-uint64_t(&i) << std::endl;
    i = int(t.data[0]);
    usePassByValue(t,uint64_t(&i));
}

int main(void){
    int i;
    std::cout << "Base Stack: " << std::hex << &i << std::dec << std::endl;
    structWithSize_s t;
    std::cout << "Sizeof(t): " << sizeof(t) <<  std::endl;
    usePassByRef(t,uint64_t(&i));
    char d;
    std::cin >> d;
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
$ g++ -std=c++0x -O0 -fno-implement-inlines -g t.cpp

$ ./a.out
Base Stack: 0x7ffff2826c8c
Sizeof(t): 2048
usePassByRef: stack: 0x7ffff282645c size on stack: 2096
usePassByValue: stack: 0x7ffff2825c1c size on stack: 2112
usePassPointer: stack: 0x7ffff2825bdc size on stack: 64
```

Comment: The pass-by-reference size is the size of the original object, not additional space.

Comment: Got that.  If the reference is an alias in the code and doesn't make a copy, why is a copy on the stack?

Comment: Its not a copy, its the original.

Comment: A reference should just be a hidden pointer, not a copy of the object.

Comment: @Barmar I think not. What a reference is is implementation dependent. It can also be optimized away completely.

Comment: @Beginner True, but the typical implementation is either a pointer or nothing at all.

Comment: @Both The code example above clearly show the reference is using memory on the stack.  I thought in the compiler a reference would be a pointer but this doesn't seem to be the case in the code above.  I thought passing by reference would not blow my stack but it did!

Comment: There's a copy because you're making a copy, specifically when `usePassByRef` calls `usePassByValue`.

Comment: You have two variables in two functions. You somehow expect that the difference of their addresses is the size of the stack frame of the second function. It's not. In order to measure the frame size, you cannot use an address *within* the frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method of testing the stack size is... unreliable to put it mildly.

Why not going straight to the horses's mouth:

Let's set up the scene:

```
struct X {
  char data[1024];
};

void by_value(X x);
void by_ref(X& x);
void by_ptr(X* x);

void test_by_value()
{
    X x;
    by_value(x);
}

void test_by_ref()
{
    X x;
    by_ref(x);
}

void test_by_ptr()
{
    X x;
    by_ptr(&x);
}
```

And now let's see what we actually have:

```
test_by_value():                     # @test_by_value()
        sub     rsp, 2056 // <-- stack increase
        lea     rsi, [rsp + 1032]
        mov     ecx, 128
        mov     rdi, rsp
        rep movsq
        call    by_value(X)
        add     rsp, 2056
        ret

test_by_ref():                       # @test_by_ref()
        sub     rsp, 1032  // <-- stack increase
        lea     rdi, [rsp + 8]
        call    by_ref(X&)
        add     rsp, 1032
        ret

test_by_ptr():                       # @test_by_ptr()
        sub     rsp, 1032  // <-- stack increase
        lea     rdi, [rsp + 8]
        call    by_ptr(X*)
        add     rsp, 1032
        ret
```

As you can see in the `test_by_value` the stack is increased by 2056 which is roughly the size of the local `x` variable (1024) + the size of the copied parameter + other stack shenanigans.

While in both `test_by_ref` and `test_by_ptr` the stack is increased by `1032` which proves that the object `x` is not duplicated on the stack.

There you have: empirical proof that passing by reference doesn't use the stack for the entire object.

---

Coming back to your testing method. In high-school and to some degree in faculty I was shown "stack concepts" by doing things the same way you are: observing addresses of local variables and comparing them.

However I have an aversion for this method. Not even talking about the portability issue. But unless you understand very well the ABI contract and the compiler implementation and optimization implementations (yes, compiler does some optimizations even with `-O0`), you get results that you don't really understand where they come from and you rush to give them interpretations that are not true.

---

you can see it in action here: https://godbolt.org/g/8562LD

clang trunk with

```
-std=c++1z -Wall -Wextra -O3 -fno-implement-inlines -march=native
```

gcc gives similar results

Answer (score 2):

> I thought using pass by reference would not make a copy of the object

Indeed, it does not.

> How much memory does a reference use on the stack

Possibly none at all if no storage is needed.

However, unless the function is expanded inline, a reference argument has to have storage in practice. Here is a trick to get the size that a reference would occupy in memory:

```
struct test {
    structWithSize_s &t;
};

size_t size = sizeof(test);
```

In practice, it is probably going to be exactly the same as a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`i` is before `structWithSize_s t` on the stack.  `sizeof(structWithSize_s)` is what you are measuring, not `sizeof(structWithSize_s &)`.

Move `i` below `structWithSize_s t`.